# Is there a functional cooldown for TPS

Tags: python, pygame

Let me start by saying I have a very limited knowledge of python and pygame. After working through a few tutorials I decided to try making a Top-Down Shooter game using pygame, based on  a few online tutorials I found. The program works so far, but I am struggling with a reload function that will initiate a cooldown on the player's gun for a few seconds while out of ammo.  I have searched for several hours for anything relating to a cooldown that I could use, and I haven't been able to make anything work. Thanks in advance for any help or advice, anything to point me in the right direction.

Here is the link to the tutorial the game is based on:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/24252/beginning-game-programming-for-teens-with-python

and here is the code I am struggling with:

```
if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                shoot.play()
                position=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                acc[1]+=1
                arrows.append([math.atan2(position[1]-(playerpos1[1]+32), position[0]-(playerpos1[0]+26)),playerpos1[0]+32,playerpos[1]+32])
```

This fires the projectile, but I want to add an ammo count and a function to cooldown once ammo is 0

Some things I've tried have been using pygame's timer function, and also the utils mod, but I couldn't get either to work for my scenario.

Here's an example of what i've tried:

```
def fire():
    global ammo # ammo = 10
    if ammo == 0:
        cooldown #  cooldown would be the timer, which i can't figure out
        ammo == 10
    else:
        arrows.append([math.atan2(position[1]-(playerpos1[1]+32), position[0]-(playerpos1[0]+26)),playerpos1[0]+32,playerpos[1]+32])
        ammo-=1

if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    shoot.play()
    position=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    acc[1]+=1
    fire()
```

Thanks for any help and suggestions, sorry if my post is poorly formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a little bit of syntax error in your fire() function. Firstly, cooldown (which I assume is a function) must be called with empty parentheses: cooldown(). Secondly, you aren't resetting ammo to 10. Instead, you ask whether ammo is already equal to 10. Here's the fixes:

```
def fire():
    global ammo
    if ammo == 0:
        cooldown() # call cooldown function with
        ammo = 10 # reset ammo
```

Hope this helped, comment if I left something out and I'll edit :)

EDIT: You asked for a cooldown() example, so here you go.
One way to do this without stopping your whole game would be to create a counter variable to run parallel with your game loop. For example:

```
COUNTER = 0
can_fire = True
while True:
    COUNTER += 1

    def fire():
        global ammo
        if not can_fire:
            if COUNTER == cooldown_count + 50: # Or however many loops
                can_fire = True
                ammo = 10
        else:
            pass
        if ammo == 0 and can_fire:
            cooldown_count = COUNTER
            can_fire = False
```

Comment: Thanks for the fixes, but my problem is actually the cooldown function. I haven't been able to find a timer that I can use for it, and I was hoping someone would suggest one that I could try.